# Problems Converting Images from 8-bit to 10-bit

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, python-imaging-library, bit-depth

I am trying to convert 8 bit images to 10 bit. I thought it would be as easy as changing the bin values. I've tried to pillow and cv-python:

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
import cv2

path = 'path/to/image'
img = Image.open(path)
data = asarray(img)

newdata = (data/255)*1023 #2^10 is 1024
img2 = Image.fromarray(newdata) #this fails

cv2.imwrite('path/newimage.png, newdata)
```

While `cv2.imwrite` successfully writes the new file, it is still encoded as an 8bit image even though bin goes up to 1023.

```
$ file newimage.png
newimage.png: PNG Image data, 640 x 480, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

Is there another way in either python or linux that can convert 8-bit to 10-bit?

Comment: Why do you need 10-bit images ? It is very uncommon and inefficient (in case of performance). Your processor and memory probably does not work well with 10-bit data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using `pgmagick` wrapper for python

```
import pgmagick as pgm

imagePath = 'path/to/image.png'
saveDir = '/path/to/save'

img = pgm.Image(imagePath)
img.depth(10) #sets to 10 bit

save_path = os.path.join(saveDir,'.'.join([filename,'dpx']))
img.write(save_path)
```

Answer (score 3):

Lots of things going wrong here.

1. You are mixing OpenCV (`cv2.imwrite`) with PIL (`Image.open`) for no good reason. Don't do that, you will confuse yourself as they use different RGB/BGR orderings and conventions,
2. You are trying to store 10-bit numbers in 8-bit vectors,
3. You are trying to hold 3 16-bit RGB pixels in a PIL Image which [will not work](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) as RGB images must be 8-bit in PIL.

---

I would suggest:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv2.imread(IMAGE, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

res = im.astype(np.uint16) * 4
cv2.imwrite('result.png', res)
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my use of mixing openCV and pillow. When I ```$ file image.png```, it now shows a 16 bit image, not 10. I haven't found any examples of 10 bit images working in openCV

Comment: @theastronomist PNG [does not support 10 bits per channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Pixel_format).  With the compression that's built in, there's no need - 16 bits will encode 10 bits without creating an overly large file.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. As Mark says, PNG doesn't support 10 bits per channel and you are more or less obliged to move to 16 bits. OpenCV itself doesn't really support 10-bit either; it too will use 16-bit types to hold 10-bit values.