# Problems writing 10-bit/color (Bit Depth) alpha-channelled image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, bit-depth

I am trying to create images with **10-bit/color** (Bit Depth) using [Image](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) module.
I wrote the following snippet, but resulting in 8-bit/color:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.new("RGBA", (256, 256))
pix = im.load()

for y in range(256):
    for x in range(256):
        pix[x, y] = (1023, 1023, 1023, 255)

im.show()
im.save("10bit.jpg")
```

While image successfully writes the new file, it still encoded as an 8-bit channel:

```
$ exiftool 10bit.png
Bit Depth                       : 8

$ file 10bit.png
10bit.png: PNG image data, 256 x 256, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

My goal here to write [Deep color (40-bit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth) images:

> Deep color consists of a billion or more colors.[15] 230 is 1,073,741,824. Usually this is 10 bits each of red, green, and blue (10 bpc). If an alpha channel of the same size is added then each pixel takes 40 bits.

What I am missing here? Is there another way to create 10-bit alpha-channeled images? *(opencv, etc.)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems Converting Images from 8-bit to 10-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64541555/problems-converting-images-from-8-bit-to-10-bit)

Comment: JPEG only supports 8-bit depth.

Comment: `Image.new("RGBA", (256, 256))` -- the `RGBA` part specifies the image to be "4x8-bit pixels, true color with transparency mask". So, since you explicitly created an 8-bit image, why would you expect it to be saved as anything but that?

Comment: Actually does not. I'm mostly looking for 10-bit raw image creation from pixels array, instead of converting from 8-bit. --- I clearly didn't mean to create an explicitly 8-bit image, what value should have I use there? I could not find much here about 10-bit pixels: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with `PIL/Pillow`. The available modes are described [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) and there are no RGB modes with more than 8-bits per pixel.

I would suggest you use `Numpy` with `HxWx3` channels of `np.uint16` to create your images and process them with `scikit-image`, or **OpenCV** or [wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand/), like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Crete empire black image
image = np.zeros((H,W,3), np.uint16)
```

You don't say explicitly what format you want to write the results in. If you clarify that, maybe I (or somebody else) can suggest a Python library.

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm not familiar with formats, however, any format that I can open with Gimp, PS, etc. is OK for me. IIUC, "HxWx3" where w (width), h (height) of an Image and 3 indicates the three colors per pixel, which is RGB. Should I use `HxWx4` here (RGBA) if I wanted to create alpha-channel?

Comment: Yes, HxWx4 is good for RGBA, but ultimately you are going to want to be able to save to disk. Maybe you want to use PAM format which **ImageMagick**, `wand`, **gimp** and Photoshop (I believe) can read. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PAM_graphics_format Or TIFF can handle RGBA 16-bit if you use `tifffile` on PyPi.